# Theta Functions which never vanish

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, theta-functions

**Definition:** Given a lattice $\Gamma \subset \mathbb C$, a Theta function $\vartheta: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is a holomorphic function with the following property:

$$ \vartheta(z+ \gamma) = e^{2i\pi a_{\gamma}z+b_{\gamma}}\vartheta(z)$$

for every $\gamma \in \Gamma$, and $ a_{\gamma},b_{\gamma} \in \mathbb C$.

> **Exercise:** A Theta function never vanishes iff $\vartheta(z) = e^{p(z)}$ with $p(z)$ a polynomial of degree at most 2.

**Thoughts/Hint:** The "only if" part is trivial. The hint is: show that $\log(\vartheta(z))=O(1 + |z|^2)$. I tried to apply log on both sides, or derive one and two times, or everything I could have thought of. I don't get where the square comes from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the derivative of $\log \vartheta$, i.e. at the function

$$q \colon z \mapsto \frac{\vartheta'(z)}{\vartheta(z)}.$$

By assumption, $q$ is an entire function, and from the property of $\vartheta$ we find

$$\vartheta'(z+\gamma) = 2\pi i a_\gamma e^{2\pi i a_\gamma z + b_\gamma}\vartheta(z) + e^{2\pi i a_\gamma z + b_\gamma}\vartheta'(z),$$

whence

$$q(z + \gamma) = 2\pi i a_\gamma + q(z)$$

for each $\gamma \in \Gamma$.

From this relation deduce that $q$ is a polynomial of degree $\leqslant 1$. (Consider a fundamental parallelogram of $\Gamma$, and a corresponding basis $\omega_1,\, \omega_2$ of $\Gamma$.) Then, since we have $p' = q$ for $p$ such that $\vartheta(z) \equiv e^{p(z)}$, it follows that such a $p$ is a polynomial of degree $\leqslant 2$.

Comment: It seems though as I miss how to show that $q$ is a polynomial and of such a degree!

Comment: For $z$ in the fundamental parallelogram, can you find a bound for $\lvert q(z + m\cdot \omega_1 + n\cdot \omega_2)\rvert$ where $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ using the relation $q(z+\gamma) = 2\pi i a_\gamma + q(z)$? That bound should imply at most linear growth of $q$.

Comment: Setting $z=0$ we get $q(m\omega_1 + n \omega_2) =c_1 m + c_2 n + q(0)$ that should work I hope!

Comment: Pretty much. Note that the fundamental parallelogram is compact, hence $q$ is bounded there. Then use that there are positive constants with $k(\lvert m\rvert + \lvert n\rvert) \leqslant \lvert m\omega_1 + n\omega_2\rvert \leqslant K(\lvert m\rvert + \lvert n\rvert)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer maybe you can be interested in this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559940/question-on-the-zeros-of-a-theta-function