# Question on the zeros of a theta function

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, number-theory, analysis, algebraic-number-theory

I really need help for this issue which should be not so difficult.

Consider $\mathbb C^n$ and let $\theta$ be an entire theta function not identically zero with respect to a lattice $\Lambda\subset\mathbb C^n$.

> Prove that for a fixed $z\in\mathbb C^n$ we can always find $a,b\in\mathbb C^n$ such that $\theta(z-a)\theta(z-b)\theta(z+a+b)\not=0$

Of course we have two possibilities: if $\theta(z)\not=0$ then just pick $a=b=0$ and we are done but I don't get the case when $\theta(z)=0$.

Hence there must be $c\in\mathbb C^n$ such that $\theta(c)\not=0$ since $\theta$ is not identically zero and so we could choose $a=z-c$ but then I can't find $b$ such that $\theta(z-b)\theta(2z-c+b)\not=0$.

Thank you for your help

Comment: It is an holomorphic function $\theta:\mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C$ such that for every $z\in\mathbb C^n$ and every $\lambda\in \Lambda$ one has $\theta(z+\lambda)=\theta(z)e^{2\pi i({L(z,\lambda)+J(\lambda)})}$ where $L$ is $\mathbb C$-linear in $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a particular property of theta functions. If $f \colon \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function that is not identically zero, then for every $z \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and every $k \geqslant 1$ we can find nonzero distinct $a_m$, $1 \leqslant m \leqslant k$ such that

$$f(z + a_1 + \dotsc + a_k)\prod_{m = 1}^k f(z-a_m) \neq 0.$$

For, since $f$ is not identically $0$, its zero set $Z(f) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}^n : f(z) = 0\}$ has empty interior. So given any $b_1,\dotsc, b_k$, and an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$, there are $c_1,\dotsc, c_k$ with $\lvert c_m - b_m\rvert < \varepsilon$ such that $f(z - c_m) \neq 0$ for $1 \leqslant m \leqslant k$. By continuity, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(z - c_m - w) \neq 0$ for all $w\in \mathbb{C}^n$ with $\lvert w\rvert < \delta$, and all $m$. Then, since $Z(f)$ has empty interior, there is a $w$ with $\lvert w\rvert < \delta$ such that $f(z + c_1 + \dotsc + c_k + w) \neq 0$. Let $a_m = c_m$ for $1 \leqslant m < k$, and $a_k = c_k + w$. If the initial $b_m$ have been chosen nonzero and distinct, the obtained $a_m$ will be nonzero and distinct if we choose $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ small enough.